# React Native nested StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

Nesting a StackNavigator

Inside my App.js

```
const MainNav = StackNavigator({
  Login : { screen : Login },
  MainPage : { screen : MainPage }
  }, {
    navigationOptions : { header : false }
  }
);
....
render() { return ....
<MainNav />
```

This is used to Navigate between Login and MainPage and it is working fine

Then inside my MainPage has another StackNavigator

```
const SubNav = StackNavigator({
  Send : { screen : Send },
  Receive : { screen : Receive }
  }, {
    navigationOptions : { header : false }
  }
);
....
render() { return ....
<Button />   //click to go to send
<Button />   //click to go to receive
<SubNav />
```

I am using:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Send');
 this.props.navigation.navigate('Receive');
```

Now, navigating between Send and Receive is not allowed. I've check the Buttons and it working fine using alert('msg'). I am rendering the Send Screen but not the Receive Screen.

I tried to  this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'); and i got redirected to the Login Screen.

Anyone pls help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons navigating to "Send" and "Receive" are using the `navigation` prop for the top level StackNavigator. You need to use the `navigation` prop of the `SubNav`, you can do this with a ref:

```
class Blah extends Component {

    subNav = null

    render() {
        return ....
            <Button onPress={this.gotoReceive} />
            <Button onPress={this.gotoSend} />
            <SubNav ref={this.refSubNav} />
    }

    refSubNav = el => this.subNav = el

    gotoSend = () => this.subNav.navigation.navigate('send')

}
```